How can a gradio dataframe hide some columns?
I am using gradio dataframes to show some pandas dataframes. I wonder if it is possible to hide some columns when displaying.
I search the internet and I found these two resources:

Here it explains how to style your dataframe in gradio by using pandas styler

Here is functionality of styler that I am interested in


So I put the two of them together and I wrote the following
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import gradio as gr

# Sample dataframe
data = {
    "Image Path": ["path1", "path2"],
    "Result": ["result1", "result2"],
    "Check": [True, False],
    "aVal": [1, 2],
    "aMatch": ["yes", "no"],
    "Hiddenelement": ["hidden1 this is a very big thing incredibly", "hidden2 this is also a huge thing with {} etc"]
    
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Define the columns including the hidden one
result_columns = ["Image Path", "Result", "Check", "aVal", "aMatch", "Hiddenelement"]

# Apply the Styler to hide the "GTelement" column
styler = df.style.hide(subset=['Hiddenelement'], axis=1)
print(f"styler {styler}")

def show_dataframe():
    print(styler)
    return styler

with gr.Blocks() as demo:
    dataframe_output = gr.DataFrame(
        label="Results Dataframe",
        headers=result_columns[:-1],  # Exclude the hidden column header
        column_widths=["20%", "65%", "5%", "5%", "5%"],
        wrap=True,
        interactive=False,
        type="pandas",
    )
    button = gr.Button("Show DataFrame")
    button.click(show_dataframe, outputs=dataframe_output)


demo.launch(server_name="0.0.0.0", server_port=7863)


However I have two issues with this

It hides the column but not its effect. Yes I cannot see it but it affects the height of the row so much

I actually need the gradio dataframe of type array.


Is there any way to hide one column when showing the data?
